# How to disable bluetooth continuously scan devices on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: usb, sound, 20.04, bluetooth, headphones

guys. Due to my bluetooth headphone(Audio-Technica ATH-SR30BT) sounds disorted and maybe interrupt when I use Ubuntu 20.04, which I have verified that my headphone is OK via testing it on Windows,

So I google it, and someone said maybe this disorted phenomenon is caused by Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth continuously scan devices.

So the question is how to disable the bluetooth continuously scan devices?

`lsusb`
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

bluez version: 5.53

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: This should be on Unix & Linux SE or Super User SE instead since it is not just for Ubuntu, but also other Linux Distributions like Fedora. There is a much younger cross-site duplicate of this at Super User [Can the traffic spew in bluetoothctl's interactive mode be turned off?](https://superuser.com/q/1777137/1192848).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try in terminal

`bluetoothctl`
Then when it shows a prompt type `scan off` then type `exit`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  But when I did as your answer, I get an error: org.bluez.Error.Failed. I will Google it and try to sovle it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The command was not enough (but I did not get an error). My  Linux Bluetooth menu was still open and it went on scanning. As in the other answer, I had to close this Linux Bluetooth menu to get rid of the scanning. I cannot say whether both the command and the closing was needed since I did both in a row, but it might be that you need both steps. Someone else please drop a remark.

Answer (score 2):

You might have your gnome control center bluetooth GUI open, which forces the scan to be on and can apparently overwhelm bluetooth.

I had a similar issue where my headphones would stop working over and over, typing `scan off` in bluetoothctl always returned an error, but the solution was simply to close the GUI.